# How to write two equations on same row without using vspace

Tags: math-mode

I want to get my math equation and their supporting statement on the same row as shown below:

[image]

How can I achieve this without using vspase inside math equation?

Comment: (1) This is not a _please do this for me_ service, please show what you have so far. Note this is easy with a two alignment column `align`, (2) since `vspace` is vertical, how does that fit into this request?

Answer (score 4):

Long stacks (from [`tab`]`stackengine` package(s)) use a fixed baselineskip.  Thus, regardless of the height of the content on any given line, two adjacent `\[...]Centerstack`s can achieve the staggered look you seek.  The parameter to play with is the long-stack baselineskip, settable with `\setstackgap{L}{<length>}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine,amssymb}
\TABstackMath
\TABstackMathstyle{\displaystyle}
\begin{document}
\[
\setstackgap{L}{30pt}
\alignCenterstack{
  & \frac{x}{2} + \frac{x}{2}\\
 =& s\Bigl(\frac{x}{2}\Bigr)\\
 =& x\\
 =& 4
}
\qquad\qquad
\tabbedCenterstack[l]{
  (\because a + a = 2a)\\
  \Bigl(\because \frac{a}{a} = 1\Bigr)\\
  (\because\textrm{given } x = 4)
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with `witharrows`. By default, we have arrows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{witharrows}
\usepackage{amssymb} % for \because
\begin{document}
\begin{DispWithArrows*}[interline = 3mm] %TikzCode= {\path (#1) to node {#3} (#2) ;}]
& \frac{x}{2} + \frac{x}{2} 
   \Arrow{$(\because a + a = 2a)$}\\
& = s\Bigl(\frac{x}{2}\Bigr) 
   \Arrow{$\Bigl(\because \frac{a}{a} = 1\Bigr)$}\\
& = x 
   \Arrow{$(\because \textrm{ given } x = 4)$}\\
& = 4
\end{DispWithArrows*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But you can suppress the arrows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{witharrows}
\usepackage{amssymb} % for \because
\begin{document}
\begin{DispWithArrows*}[interline = 3mm,
                        TikzCode= {\path (#1) to node {#3} (#2) ;}]
& \frac{x}{2} + \frac{x}{2} 
   \Arrow{$(\because a + a = 2a)$}\\
& = s\Bigl(\frac{x}{2}\Bigr) 
   \Arrow{$\Bigl(\because \frac{a}{a} = 1\Bigr)$}\\
& = x 
   \Arrow{$(\because \textrm{ given } x = 4)$}\\
& = 4
\end{DispWithArrows*}
\end{document}
```

[image]